# JSF Extended Datatable selective sorting and filtering

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a extended datatable, RICHFACES 3.3.3 with sorting and filtering enabled. The table is rendered **dynamically**. Based on the requirement, I need to disable certain rows(which contain editable fields) when the table is displayed. I have that logic written in a javascript function **rowBlur()**, and call it whenever the page is displayed. Hence, when the table is loaded the required rows are disabled as expected. The problem is whenever I filter/sort the table, the disabled rows get enabled again.

Is there any way I can call the javascript function whenever filter or sort happens.

```
HtmlExtendedDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlExtendedDataTable();
dynamicDataTable.setOnkeydown("filterAllOnEnter(event)");

function filterAllOnEnter(event)
    {
       if(event.keyCode == 13)
       {
          jQuery(".rich-filter-input").blur();
          rowblur();
          return false;
       }
       else return true;
    }
```

The **rowblur()** won't work properly on filtering, and on sorting the columns it won't work at all.

Comment: I am new to this forum, I don't know what nonsense did I do that erased the @BalusC reply. Sorry for that.

Comment: `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()`
seem to work with JSF 2? I am using JSF 1.2 :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you just lost track of your original question. Please edit _that_ one to add any additional information you might have. No worries :)

Comment: @TimPost, I posted a new question too (JSF Extended Datatable Sorting and Filtering).. but didn't get the solution... :(

Comment: @BalusC I know its a duplicate question.. I purposely added a new one.. so that you may come across it.. Please help.. :(

Comment: I made some minor edits to that, it was a little hard to read at first. I think you'll do fine, just be patient :)